# How to switch from a part to another part

Tags: vim

I am new at vim. And I have a thing to ask you.

For instance, when I open two parts of the project, one is vim editor, another one is the file browser, like this.

[image: image about the question]

As you can see, we have two parts: the file browser and the editor.

I want to switch from the file browser to the editor, is this available in vim?

Comment: Ctrl+W l, see `:help ^w` and https://superuser.com/questions/280500/how-does-one-switch-between-windows-on-vim

Answer (score 1):

> I am new at vim.

Then you should follow its built-in tutorial before trying random commands:

```
:help user-manual
```

Handling *windows*, not "parts", is thoroughly explained in the 8th chapter:

```
:help usr_08
```

while the built-in file explorer has its own chapter:

```
:help usr_21
```

Note the order: handling windows is taught before handling the file explorer because the former is a prerequisite of the latter.

Baby steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this mapping, the command line should be Ctrl+w then "h" to move to left or "l" to move to the right. All this in normal mode, you can set it to insert mode as well I guess.

[Mapping to move around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8z10.png)

In my case "leader" is "space"